# Response renders Jade and is sent before sqlite3 finishes query

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sqlite

I'm trying to get results from an sqlite3 database and get them to render in a jade template but based on the combination of logs I placed in this code it seems as if the template is rendered while waiting for the db query to finish.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('test_dab');

/* GET home page. */

var rowResults;


router.get('/', function(req, res) {


    db.get('SELECT ID, first_name, last_name FROM customer WHERE ID = 33', function(err,  row){
        rowResults = 'Hello, ' + row.first_name + ' ' + row.last_name + '!';
        console.log(row);
        console.log(rowResults);
    });


    console.log(rowResults);

    res.render('index', { title: 'Express',
        whatever: rowResults });
});

console.log('Router found index');
module.exports = router;
```

Here is the output in the console:

```
//on browser refresh...

undefined
GET / 304
{ ID: 22, first_name: 'Bo', last_name: 'Jackson' }
Hello, Bo Jackson!
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304
GET /javascripts/main.js 304
```

How do I keep the page from rendering before the db is finished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `db.get` method is asynchronous. The way you're doing, `render` is being executed before `db.get` returns and set the `rowResults` variable.

You have to call the `render` method inside your `db.get` method call:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  db.get('SELECT ID, first_name, last_name FROM customer WHERE ID = 33', function(err,  row){
    var rowResults = 'Hello, ' + row.first_name + ' ' + row.last_name + '!';
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express',
    whatever: rowResults });
  });
});
```